# Android make a counter descending?

Tags: android

im an **beginner** .. and i wanna do a **counter descending** when my program start like .. **:**
5
4
3
2
1
START SOMTHING

simple

thanks

Comment: Could you clarify your question, please?  Do you want to know how to subtract two numbers?  How to use a timer in Android?  How to display a graphic (like a status bar)?  Something else entirely?  Have you tried anything yourself yet?

Comment: **i tryed Timer , Sleep but i failed .. all i need is something like textview = 5 then one second then it goes 4 then one second 3 ..**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it in various ways, one way would be to use CountdownTimer class in Android.

An example can be found here:
[How can I start and stop my countdowntimer via a button?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4788086/how-can-i-start-and-stop-my-countdowntimer-via-a-button)

Answer (score 2):

I think this will give you a good starting point ...

```
package com.example.countdown;

import java.util.Timer;
import java.util.TimerTask;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class CountdownDemoActivity extends Activity {
    private TextView number;
    private int countdownNumber = 5;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);

        number = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.number);

        TimerTask countdownTask = new TimerTask() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                        if(countdownNumber == 0) {
                            cancel();
                        }
                        number.setText(String.valueOf(countdownNumber));
                        countdownNumber--;
                    }
                });
            }
        };

        Timer countdown = new Timer();
        countdown.schedule(countdownTask, 0, 1000);
    }
}
```

Comment: Two different solutions to the same problem :) hope it helps